# Raspberry PI UART doesn't work all the time

Tags: python, raspbian-stretch, uart

I am trying to communicate to a UART device using Raspberry Pi (Raspberry Pi 3B with Raspbian stretch) Header pins with pyserial. I have followed all the steps mentioned in https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md  to activate the UART over Header pins (Like editing the /boot/cmdline.txt file, disabling the UART over bluetooth ) . I am able to communicate to the device and get the data but this is not working all time but on a cyclic basis. If I run the program for the first time it works fine. If I close the program and run it again , then I am receiving all the blank values. If I close the program and run it again , I am receiving the perfect output. This happens repeatedly. Is there anything I am doing wrong ?? 
Below is the code i am using.

```
import time
import serial
try:
    ser = serial.Serial()
    ser.port = '/dev/serial0'
    ser.baudrate = 115200
    ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS 
    ser.parity =serial.PARITY_NONE 
    ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE 
    ser.timeout = 1
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    pass
print(ser)

while True:
    try:
        ser.open()
        data=str(ser.readline())
        ser.close()
        print(data)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
```

I am trying to figure out what's going wrong with this for 1.5 days now. Somebody please help :(

Answer (score 1):

It is totally un-necessary (and counter-productive) to disable the UART over bluetooth.
For all, but the most demanding tasks the mini UART functions perfectly well, any doesn't disable Bluetooth. In any event it is better to use `raspi-config` to change settings rather than editing files.

*End of sermon* - now to your problem, you have the following code which continually opens and closes the port, leaving you with an undefined state in the buffer.

```
while True:
    try:
        ser.open()
        …
        ser.close()
        …
```

Open the serial port **ONCE** at the start of your program and close it at the end.

Even then on initial run the buffer may contain data, you should flush or discard first read.